# sum of values in each column in a database table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

Table name is `List`.
I have to get sum of each column. I cannot give this query:

```
SELECT SUM(jayesh,murali,jins) from List;
```

because the columns are added dynamically. Column names are given as user input. Is there any other code to do this..?

Comment: You want to take the sum of multiple columns?

Comment: Do you want to sum the columns of one record or the columns of all records? What is the desired result at all?

Comment: Why would you ever have names hard coded into a table like this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want the sum of all columns combined for all records (one sum for entire table)? The sum of all columns for each record (one sum for each row)? The sum of each column separately for all records (one sum for each column)? What is the expected output and what is the goal of this?

Comment: incredible! please tell me that you add programmatically a column for any new user

Comment: ... *because the columns are added dynamically* ...; this is a bad idea. actually it is **wrong** to change table's structure dynamically based on user input (except for very few cases, this is not in it). review the table structure. normalize it. if you need help in that direction, then we would be happy. by as it stands now, you are going in wrong direction.

Comment: yes,sir.. i add programmatically a column for any new user

Comment: Do you add a new column to the table or to the query? Those are very different things.

Comment: to the table.. Is there any way to add new column to the query..?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum *in each* column:

```
SELECT SUM(jayesh), SUM(murali), SUM(jns) from List;
```

Comment: i cant use sum(jayesh) because column name 'jayesh' is entered at run time

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more of your context. NOT your whole code base please, just enough so we understand what you mean. We have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: You need to produce the query at runtime as well. This is considered a dynamic query. Since you're already going down the a bad path with the dynamic tables, you might as well keep going down it with some dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

Not saying that any of this is or is not a good idea because no context was provided, but...

**Sum of all columns combined for all records (one sum for entire table):**

```
SELECT SUM(jayesh+murali+jns)
FROM List
```

**Sum of all columns for each record (one sum for each row):**
(This option requires having an id column to group by so that you can determine how to group the rows)

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(jayesh+murali+jns)
FROM List
GROUP BY ID
```

**Sum of each column separately for all records (one sum for each column):**

```
SELECT
    SUM(jayesh), 
    SUM(murali), 
    SUM(jns)
FROM List
```

I would also recommend reconsidering your design in adding dynamic columns based on user input. This is generally not a good idea, certainly not for this case. Read more here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html